# Manga about people having guarding animal spirits

Tags: story-identification, manga

This manga  had everyone born with an animal spirit. Those who get strong ones become important and powerful. The main character get a "boring" cat and goes to a school to train the guardians. Turns out his cat was a legendary tiger hiding.

Answer (score 6):

Is this the WEBTOON *[Flow](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/flow/list?title_no=101)*? (Now available as a Daily Pass series, that is, wait to read for free.)

The [wiki](https://webtoon.fandom.com/wiki/Flow) explains:

> Yun Lee-Rang is a young man with a cat anima. After being beat up and put into the hospital his cat anima is revealed to be one of the strongest animas in disguise; the White Tiger. The White Tiger anima allows him to cast a wish and he uses it to turn back time. He soon repeats the cycle of his day but several consequences were found with turning back time.

[image: my god came to me 10 years ago. (Cat says:) “I can give you a special gift”]

At the school, everyone uses their animal-based powers to fight, as seen in (for example) episodes 8-9.

I believe the white tiger form shows up in episode 22. (Not to be confused with another character’s Bengal tiger.)

Comment: Yes thank you very much!