# Manga about a boy who sees a God in the street and later meets kids who have different animal spirits (tiger, dragon)

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember reading this manga book when I was little — about 10 or 11 years ago – and the story is about a boy. I don't know if he's in school or not, but he like sees a God in the street and after that he's realized all things near him are like animated.

I think he becomes like somehow a servant or apostle of the God, and he's transferred to a sacred or forbidden forest where he later meets another boy who's possessed by a spirit of a white tiger.

The boy can fuse with the white tiger, and also use the white tiger's power etc, and I remember there's later another girl in the book with the spirit of a Dragon who can do the same thing.

There's a few people who possess the spirit and can use the spirits power, similar to power rangers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be the WEBTOON *[Flow](https://www.webtoons.com/en/fantasy/flow/list?title_no=101)*, which started being published in 2014. It isn't an isekai, however, but many of the details match, at least as much as I remember, such as a kid with a dragon anima and another with a tiger. It's now available as a Daily Pass series, that is, wait to read for free.

The [wiki](https://webtoon.fandom.com/wiki/Flow) explains:

> Yun Lee-Rang is a young man with a cat anima. After being beat up and put into the hospital his cat anima is revealed to be one of the strongest animas in disguise; the White Tiger. The White Tiger anima allows him to cast a wish and he uses it to turn back time. He soon repeats the cycle of his day but several consequences were found with turning back time.

[image: my god came to me 10 years ago. (Cat says:) “I can give you a special gift”]

At the school, everyone uses their animal-based powers to fight, as seen in (for example) episodes 8-9.

I believe the white tiger form shows up in episode 22. (Not to be confused with another character’s Bengal tiger.)

(Copied with minor changes from my [previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/243275/82909).)